# What is a Ground Power Dispatch Switch?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, electrical-system, equipment, mel

I've been going over the new [Master Minimum Equipment List (MMEL) for Textron Aviation Model 500 Series Citations](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=M%20CE-500%20R9a) and on page 36 a Ground Power Dispatch Switch is mentioned but I can't find any information or pictures of it online.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Citations have an auxiliary battery in the nose that lets you power up limited avionics, like a comm radio and one of the FMS units and displays, to allow you to get your clearance and program the FMS before engine start, in the absence of a ground power cart, without having to deplete the main battery.  It's controlled by the Ground Power Dispatch Switch.